# How is the DOM parsed?

Tags: html, xml, dom, domparser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If you're not supposed to use Regular Expressions to parse HTML, then how are HTML parsers written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400623/if-youre-not-supposed-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-then-how-are-htm)

My question is simple: How do current DOM parsers *actually* parse the DOM from a string (XML, HTML, or otherwise)?

I know [you shouldn't parse html with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), but couldn't a DOM parser use RegEx to match patterns for open/close tags? Or, is there a good once-over algorithm for parsing the provided string as a character array?

Comment: Depends on the parser implementation doesn't it?

Comment: But to answer this exact question quickly: Most propably do use regexes - but only **for tokenization** (e.g. recognizing opening and closing tags).

Comment: I missed that question somehow, and I've voted to close this copy down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this:

- [How do HTML parses work if they're not using regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400623/if-youre-not-supposed-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-then-how-are-htm)
- [Parsing HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/parsing.html#parsing):

[image]

[**Here is a good Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150293/how-does-a-parser-for-example-html-work/3150631#3150631)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could start with a basic approach along the lines of:

http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/parsing-html-tags-in-c

And then just expand it to store everything into the full DOM tree structure.