# Can attributes inside a tag have an extra space, is it semantically correct?

Tags: html

This could be a stupid question, but i'm at the design phase where everything is checked for semantics correctness.

For example, when having this

```
<a href="..." id="page" <?php if (false) echo 'name="test"'; ?> class="pageWidth">
```

...i believe it produces:

```
<a href="..." id="page"  class="pageWidth">
```

... notice there is a an extra space between the id attribute and the class attribute.

Now, the stupid semantic question: is this semantically correct? Can attributes have extra space and not matter at all?

Comment: Makes no difference. No one sees it and it's parsed the same regardless

Comment: Additional spaces are ignored in HTML parsing. Some people write code like `<a href = "..." id = "page">`

Comment: One of the reasons i was asking is because when i view the page source from the browser i can clearly see the extra space and i was wondering if it can have unknown consequences in the future. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150293/how-does-a-parser-for-example-html-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags):

> Attributes must be separated from each other by one **or more** space characters.

So, including an extra space between two attributes is still valid HTML.
But I don't think that formatting affects [*semantics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) of the markup, per se.

That being said, it would not be difficult to remove the extra space if you prefer.
I sometimes use a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to generate output like that:

```
<a href="..." id="page"<?= false ? ' name="test"' : '' ?> class="pageWidth">
```

Comment: personally, i prefer the extra space because the php code can be messy and it's sometimes cleaner and more readable with the extra space. And the editor i'm using, sublime text, has trouble when the string <?php is glued to a tag

Comment: @Marco That makes sense.